# Java StreamCorrupted Exception, using JSON

Tags: java, json, io

I'm not sure exactly why I am getting this error at the bottom of the code? Any help is appreciated. I understand that is has something to do with the use of the ObjectOutputStream or ObjectInputStream? Just not entirely positive. Thanks for any help in advance.

//MAIN

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class LibraryOfMovieDescriptions implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args){       

    MovieLibrary movieLibrary;
    movieLibrary = new MovieLibrary("movies.json");

    movieLibrary.toJsonFile("movies.json");
    }
}
```

//MOVIE DESCRIPTION CLASS

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MovieDescription implements Serializable {

private String title;
private String rating;
private String release;
private String runtime;
private String plot;
private String filename;
private String genre;
private String actors;

public JSONObject toJSONObject() throws JSONException {
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     obj.put("Title", title);
     obj.put("Rated", rating);
     obj.put("Released", release);
     obj.put("Runtime", runtime);
     obj.put("Plot", plot);
     obj.put("Filename", filename);


     JSONArray a = new JSONArray();
     String[] sArray = this.actors.split(" , ");
     for(int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++){
         a.put(i);
     }
     obj.put("Actors", a);

     JSONArray g = new JSONArray();
     String[] gArray = this.genre.split(" , ");
     for(int i = 0; i < gArray.length; i++){
         g.put(i);
     }
     obj.put("Genre", g);

     return obj;
}

public MovieDescription(JSONObject jsonObj) throws JSONException{               
    this.title = jsonObj.getString("Title");    
    this.rating = jsonObj.getString("Rating"); 
    this.release = jsonObj.getString("Released");
    this.plot = jsonObj.getString("Plot");
    this.runtime = jsonObj.getString("Runtime");
    this.filename = jsonObj.getString("Filename");

    JSONArray g = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Genre");
    for(int i = 0; i < g.length(); i++){
        this.genre += g.get(i) + ", ";
    }

    JSONArray a = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Actors");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        this.actors += a.get(i) + ", ";
    }
}

public MovieDescription(){
    title = " ";
    rating = " ";
    release = " ";
    runtime = " ";
    plot = " ";
    filename = " ";
    genre = " ";
    actors = " ";
}

public MovieDescription(String title, String rating, String release, String runtime, String plot, String filename,
                        String genre, String actors){
    this.title = title;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.release = release;
    this.runtime = runtime;
    this.plot = plot;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.actors = actors;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public void setRating(String rating){
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getRating(){
    return rating;
}

public void setRelease(String release){
    this.release = release;
}

public String getRelease(){
    return this.release;
}

public void setRuntime(String runtime){
    this.runtime = runtime;
}

public String getRuntime(){
    return runtime;
}

public void setPlot(String plot){
    this.plot = plot;
}

public String getPlot(){
    return plot;
}

public void setFilename(String filename){
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String getFilename(){
    return filename;
}

public void setGenre(String genre){
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getGenre(){
    return genre;
}

public void setActors(String actors){
    this.actors = actors;
}

public String getActors(){
    return actors;
}

public String toString(){
    String string = ("Title: " + title + "\n" + "Rating: " + rating + "\n" + "Released: " + release + "\n" +
    "Runtime: " + runtime + "\n" + "Plot: " + plot + "\n" + "Filename: " +    filename + "\n" + "Genre: " + genre
    + "\n" + "Actors: " + actors + "\n");

        return string;
    }

}
```

//MOVIE LIBRARY CLASS

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class MovieLibrary implements Serializable {

private List<MovieDescription> movieLib = new ArrayList<MovieDescription>();

private int arraySize;

public MovieLibrary(){
    arraySize = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return arraySize == 0;
}

public MovieDescription get(String aTitle){
    int i = indexOf(aTitle);
    if(i == -1){
        return null;
    }
    return movieLib.get(i);
}

public boolean add(MovieDescription aClip){
    movieLib.add(aClip);
    arraySize++;
    return true;
}

public boolean remove(String aTitle){
    int i = indexOf(aTitle);
    if(i != -1){
        movieLib.remove(i);
        arraySize--;
    }
    return true;
}

public String[] getTitles(){
    String[] s = new String[movieLib.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < movieLib.size(); i++){
        s[i] = movieLib.get(i).getTitle();
    }
    return s;
}

private int indexOf(String aTitle){
    for(int i = 0; i < movieLib.size(); i++)
        if(((movieLib.get(i)).getTitle()).equals(aTitle)){
            return i;
        }
    return -1;
}

public MovieLibrary(String jsonFile){ 

    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    File inFile = null;
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    String[] titles;

    try{        
        inFile = new File(jsonFile);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(in));
        titles = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj);
        System.out.println("Adding Movies...");
        for(int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
            JSONObject temp = jsonObj.getJSONObject(titles[i]);
            MovieDescription movies = new MovieDescription(temp);
            movieLib.add(movies);
        }
        System.out.println(this.getTitles());
        in.close();         
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException z){
                z.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void toJsonFile(String jsonFileName){

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;

    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < movieLib.size(); i++)
            jsonObj.put(movieLib.get(i).getTitle(),movieLib.get(i).toJSONObject());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jsonFileName));       
        out.writeObject(jsonObj.toString());
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(out != null){
            try{
            out.close();
            }
            catch(IOException z){
                z.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

And now I am getting this error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B202022
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at MovieLibrary.<init>(MovieLibrary.java:79)
  at LibraryOfMovieDescriptions.main(LibraryOfMovieDescriptions.java:11)
```

Comment: Don’t use ObjectInputStream to read JSON.  ObjectInputStream is for reading Java serialized data, which has a specific [binary format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

Comment: @VGR what do you recommend I use then? I have all of these classes implementing and importing Serializable.

Comment: That depends on your requirements.  You can use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream to perform Java serialization, but the files will not be human-readable.  If you are required to use JSON files, there are a number of JSON libraries for Java (including [Java’s own](https://jsonp.java.net/download.html)).